# Leiningen REPL still using Clojure 1.6

Tags: macos, clojure, leiningen

I would like to use Clojure 1.7 from the Leiningen REPL.

The Clojure download page at http://clojure.org/downloads leads me to believe I just need to add Clojure 1.7 as a dependency in the profile.clj file.  Which I did in `~/.lein/profiles.clj`.

```
mike@Mikes-MBP-2:~$ brew upgrade leiningen
Error: leiningen 2.5.1 already installed
mike@Mikes-MBP-2:~$ cat ~/.lein/profiles.clj
{:user
  {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]
   :plugins [[lein-pprint "1.1.1"]]
   }
}
mike@Mikes-MBP-2:~$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 54016 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:54016
REPL-y 0.3.5, nREPL 0.2.6
Clojure 1.6.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_31-b13
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=>
```

What else do I need to do to have `lein repl` use Clojure 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always run `lein repl` from the context of a project that uses Clojure 1.7.

```
(defproject sandbox "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A project to run lein repl with a specific clojure version"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-RC1"]])
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I made a new project just for REPLing.